# what is the proper syntax for calling Porperty in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, aix

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
. ./test.prop

for ((i=0; i<10;i++)
do
    echo $F($i)
done
```

The file it sources contains parameter assignments:

```
F1=20
F2=30
F3=40
.
.
.
```

The desired output of the script would be

```
10
20
30
40
.
.
.
```

What is the proper syntax for `$F($i)`? or I just can't simply use it?

Comment: What is `F`? are you reading the numbers from a file or just want to print using a loop?

Comment: regarding number from test.prop file so i want to print all F's using loop... so echo $F1...echo $F2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `eval`:

```
eval "echo \$F$i"
```

Eval is used to evaluate and then run a command, allowing you to dynamically generate the command. By escaping the first dollar symbol, it is used explicitly in the generated command, while note escaping the second dollar symbol allows us to expand its value into a number used to generate the variable name. So suppose that `$i` contains the value "1", the generated command is `echo $F1`.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: wow exactly what I as looking for.. Thanks for explanation and answers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use indirect parameter expansion:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
    f="F$i"
    echo "${!f}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do not you use an array?

```
F=(10 20 30 ...)
```

and

```
for i in {0..9}; do
    echo ${F[i]}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep command:

```
grep ^F prop.test | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

This will grep all lines that start with `F` and print the number after the `=`.